# Can you make span text disappear (and have no width)?

Tags: html, css, text

Under certain page widths I want a span of text to disappear. I can use the "visibility:hidden" which works well except it still takes up the space. I've tried changing the font size to 0px and that helps shrink the space, but it's far from eliminating it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A little googling would of solved your issue. `display: none`

Comment: Thanks! I really did google it but I wasn't googling the right phrase apparently because I couldn't find anything related to this. :)

Answer (score 4):

The following will remove the element from the page for you:

```
display:none;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
display: none;
```

Is what you are looking for. This will remove the element from the flow of the page entirely. Or,

```
width: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
```

will do essentially the same thing. Think of it as collapsing the element on itself.

Comment: What does `overflow: none;` do?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I meant hidden. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `visibility:hidden` or `display: none`

Ex: 
    `var div = document.getElementById('login');`
    `div.style.display = "none";`